# Не могу найти ошибку, подскажите

Tags: java, xml, dom

Достаю из файла XML некоторые параметры.
В файле есть 2 одинаковых блока но с разными значениями. Мне нужен тот блок где параметр тага "environment" равен "DEV".

Вот мой код:

```
private static String getFullNameOfOperation() {
    DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document document = builder.parse(new File(file));
    document.getDocumentElement().normalize();

    NodeList nList = document.getElementsByTagName("Environment");
    for (int i = 0; i < nList.getLength(); i++) {
        Node nNode = nList.item(i);

        System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode.getNodeName());

        if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

        Element eElement = (Element) 
        if(eElement.getElementsByTagName("environment").item(0).getTextContent() == "DEV") {
                System.out.println("environment : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("environment").item(0).getTextContent());
                System.out.println("version : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("version").item(0).getTextContent());
                System.out.println("updateTimestamp : "+ eElement.getElementsByTagName("updateTimestamp").item(0).getTextContent());
                System.out.println("userId : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("userId").item(0).getTextContent());
                System.out.println("userName : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("userName").item(0).getTextContent());
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return rootName.substring(0, startStr);
}
```

В дебаге вижу что приходит "DEV" но if не работает.

XML:

```
<FwMBDeployProcess.Deployment.Publish>
   <Deployment>
      <Environments>
         <Environment>
           <environment>TST</environment>
           <version>1.3.0</version>
           <updateTimestamp>2016-05-02-10.38.13.708389</updateTimestamp>
           <userId>R47</userId>
           <userName>B</userName>
         </Environment>
         <Environment>
           <environment>DEV</environment>
           <version>1.4.0</version>
           <updateTimestamp>2016-05-03-10.27.42.429521</updateTimestamp>
           <userId>R47</userId>
           <userName>A</userName>
         </Environment>
      </Environments>
   </Deployment>
</FwMBDeployProcess.Deployment.Publish>
```

Не заходит не if в не else в сразу прыгает в return.

Comment: Строки сравниваются через `equals()`.

Comment: О спасибо !! Вот я чайник.